# android imports cant be resolved in a test project

Tags: android-testing, eclipse-adt

Hi Im trying to import the demo test project from google at http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-functional-testing.html, But the following imports can't be resolver

```
import com.example.android.testingfun.R;
//this are the classes that need to be tested
import com.example.android.testingfun.lesson2.MyFirstTestActivity;
import com.example.android.testingfun.lesson3.ClickFunActivity;
import com.example.android.testingfun.lesson4.LaunchActivity;
import com.example.android.testingfun.lesson4.NextActivity;
import com.example.android.testingfun.lesson5.ReceiverActivity;
import com.example.android.testingfun.lesson5.SenderActivity;
```

Im importing the project in eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+1 fix fix project, add to build bath